# JPanel does not show up inside another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

```
class ABC extends JFrame {
    public JPanel createGUI()
    {
        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        outerPanel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel top = new JLabel();
        top.setBounds(40,40,400,30);
        top.setText("Hello World");
        outerPanel.add(top);

        int l = getLength();
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        if(l==0)
        {
            innerPanel.setLayout(null);
            JLabel empty = new JLabel("No Data Found");
            empty.setBounds(80,150,300,30);
            innerPanel.add(empty);
        }
        else
        {
            innerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(l,4,5,5)); 
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Text1");
                innerPanel.add(new JLabel("Text2");

                JButton b1 = new JButton("Button1");
                innerPanel.add(b1);
                JButton b2 = new JButton("Button2");
                innerPanel.add(b2);
            }          
         }
         outerPanel.add(innerPanel);
         return outerPanel;
    }
}
```

In the above code the innerPanel does not show up and neither any error occurs.Any idea how to show up the innerPanel which is inside an outerPanel.I tried using 
    getContentPane().add(innerPanel)
 but it didn't work.

Comment: I think the problem is innerPanel is going to have getPreferredSize() == 0,0 ... because its got nothing in it, so it isn't getting layed out by FlowLayout (the default layout manager of JPanel) if it's being added directly to the contentPane, outerPanel is probably getting displayed because calling add (component) on the default contentPane will add it with BorderLayout.CENTER

Comment: How do you even know what is getting displayed and what is not. You have added no visual elements that take space. Your label is empty and no borders are set so all elements are going to be zero in size.

Comment: @markbernard Here I have added just added the minimal code required I thought which would give a solution.I do have visual elements set up in outerPanel as well as innerPanel in which outerPanel does get rendered properly.

Comment: An out of context snippet of code isn't going to provide us with enough information to help you, other then throw "guesses" at you

Comment: `I have added just added the minimal code required` - Post a proper [mcve] when you ask a question that demonstrates the problem. 1) the code doesn't compile. 2) all you need is to add a single component to the panel so we get the idea of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
outerPanel.setLayout(null);
```

to

```
outerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

or remove the setLayout call entirely.

Comment: While a good idea, as far as I can tell, the OP has no way knowing if the panel is actually visible, as nothing visible has been added to it, so even if this "did" solve the problem, they wouldn't know

Comment: (1+) but, you can just get rid of the  setLayout(null) statement. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers and the default layout manager for a JPanel  is the FlowLayout.